# sql query to get images that are not removed from post gallery

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a gallery post, I get all the images from gallery post using this sql:

```
$gallery_sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = 67 and post_type = 'attachment' order by id desc");
```

If I remove some images from gallery post, but all the images are still showing. How to hide images that are removed from gallery images?

Comment: are the image stored on database or on disc? if it's on database you have to completely remove it from everywhere while running delete query. If images are stored on disc you have to create an array that have list of images on disc and compare it against the data you have got from `SELECT` query above by creating array from it.

Comment: Also, have you checked that this isn't a caching problem? Caching is very often the cause of problems that are "I changed this but the change didn't work on the web page"